systemd-repart doesn't seem to be working
I would like to ditch bash scripting in favor of systemd-reparted. What I'm trying to do:

From initrd, before mounting /sysroot or /sysusr grow partition /dev/mmcblk0p2 with type linux-generic.
Encrypt this partition with key-file
Create partitions inside crypted Luks container e.g. root1 root2 and data.
Format created partition with ext4
Copy from tar/folder to root1 and root2 accordingly.
Happily boot with switch_root

I'm failing on the first step:
/etc/repart.d/50-root.conf:
[Partition]
Type=linux-generic

when I try to run systemd-repart manually, I get:
~ # systemd-repart /dev/mmcblk0 --no-pager --dry-run=no 
No machine ID set, using randomized partition UUIDs.
TYPE          LABEL  UUID          FILE NODE                 SIZE        PADDING
esp           boot   dab3ebc1-604…      /dev/mmcblk0p1     100.0M             0B
linux-generic rootfs 91589d66-e3e…      /dev/mmcblk0p2     686.7M 118.6G → 118.…
                                                       Σ = 786.7M     Σ = 118.6G

 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
 ├─ rootfs                                                                     
 └─ boot                                                                       

No changes.

But in fact disk is way bigger than repart is seeing:
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119.38 GiB, 128177930240 bytes, 250347520 sectors

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible or I should stick to scripts we currently have?
